# How can I start running MySQL commands on Mac?

Tags: mysql, database, macos

I am using 10.11 and just installed the latest version of MySQL. Turned on the database using Mac terminal but after that:

```
JOHNMAC:~ Main$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'Main'@'localhost' (using 
password: NO)
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently trying to access mysql with your current user without a password. That's what the error is indicating.
Try `mysql -u root -p`
And then, enter the root password that you entered during the setup.

Comment: Could you post the whole answer you get?